# PHP Built-in web server, request uri length

Tags: php, webserver, built-in

I have a situation in the office. For development, i have been using the built-in web server that comes with PHP 5.4.

My problem is, on my local machine, it works like a charm but on the staging server, request uri length becomes a problem.

Staging server is: Ubuntu 12.10 32 bit. 
PHP Version is

```
PHP 5.4.14-1~quantal+1 (cli) (built: Apr 11 2013 16:59:23) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v2.2.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2012, by Derick Rethans
```

php.ini files are the same with the ones in my local.

I tried to recompile the PHP but still no luck. I have a simple php code to test as;

```
<?php
echo $_GET['q'];
?>
```

but when the request is too big (around 1447 chars like index.php?q=blahblah...) Built-in web server fails and just gets ....endofstring as request. So returns a 404.

I Know that every web server has a request url length limit, but while an identical request to my localhost (ubuntu 12.04, again php built-in server) works, there should be something that i miss.

Any suggestions or clues where to look for the problem?

Comment: Whatever the actual technical detail is here, the real answer is not to use URLs that are 1447 characters long...!

Comment: I believe some browsers such as IE fail on a lower number, so it's best to stay away from long urls anyway. It's a pain enough already to copy say a google maps link!

Comment: you have a point but this is going to be a web service and i pass query to the service resource. It crashes when the query is too long. It is totally natural i suppose.

Comment: On a side note, you shouldn't use the built-in webserver for anything other than development and even then that's questionable.

Comment: Why aren't you using POST?

Comment: It is a REST service, using POST for query is not a good idea for the architecture. In a usual CRUD (Create Read Update Delete) architecture, POST method is mainly used for Create actions for resources. Reading (and filtering) data is handled with GET, Update is PUT and Delete is DELETE. The problem is the query length, in Apache, it is possible to use queries up to 8190 bytes. But somehow in Ubuntu 12.10, PHP Built-in Server fails at long urls. I tested it on different machines, still the same. It is better to use 12.04 LTS as server i think. And at last, i will use Nginx as web server.